# How do security updates and patching work for Windows Server 2016 containers?

Tags: docker, windows-server-2016

If I use the new "containers" feature (managed via docker) in windows server 2016 to create a containerised application, what happens when my underlying windows server operating system receives security patches?

- Do I need to rebuild all my container images?
- Do the containers all stop working?

Answer (score 0):

> Do I need to rebuild all my container images?

Yes.

> Do the containers all stop working?

No.

Comment: If they don't stop working it implies I'm not forced to rebuild my images, but if I don't are they simply left running, but without the security patches applied?